# <kbd> value is grey and seems to be disabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, kbd

The value between `<kbd>` and `</kbd>` is grey and it seems to be disabled: <kbd>grey</kbd>

I remember that it looked better (probably the text was black = more visible) in the past, but now it looks like this:

[image: key tag]

The problem appears at least on this website and on stackoverflow.

Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34712075

I tested it using 3 different browsers:

- Chrome 49
- IE 11 (+ compatibility mode: 9 & 10)
- Firefox 39

but the problem appears on all of them.

Comment: Can you link the post this appears on?

Comment: I added an example, but it looks similar in other posts.

Comment: It seems related to the numbered list.

Comment: Not on mobile though.

Comment: someone needs to dust off the keyboard

Comment: SE made some CSS changes and borked some old stuff... happens all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. This has been corrected. Sorry for the inconvenience. The issue was a wrong color variable was selected for the text color.

Comment: Just curious, what is the goal of the recent CSS changes? Anything specific, or just minor improvements?

Comment: @ShadowWizard We're attempting to organize and consolidate our CSS to eliminate redundant styles / layouts. Performance is one concern (with smaller CSS file sizes), but also more and more people are working on the SO product and it's currently very difficult to fully understand the impact a minor change will have because of the way the CSS is currently organized.

Comment: @Hynes - You guys are growing exponentially...just wait for the days to come when you guys will take a year to roll out whether a certain sentence ends in a period or not....or the years it will take for everyone to agree whether they should use pink or blush for the background of an error message.  Growing is great but it has some weaknesses (in that it takes forever to produce / publish something that could of taken minutes).  I remember one guy who left google because he was a motivated designer that hated the fact that they would have meetings after meetings about what font to use.

Comment: @JonH Appreciate the comment. It's something we've talked about a lot recently, especially as a design team. Our solution (for right now) is we empower 2-3 people to make the decisions, informing the rest of the team of any major changes to allow them a chance to provide feedback. Ultimately those 2-3 people make the decision, but this allows others to expose potential blind spots in their thinking.